# Sql Server Cursor with exec xp_create_subdir

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to loop through all existing accounts on a SQL Server DB and create individual account folders using xp_create_subdir. However, I know what I have is not working because I'm trying to pass a variable as part of the parameter. This is my code:

```
declare @id int

declare crsr cursor LOCAL FAST_FORWARD for

select  Id
from AccountModels
where Active = 1
and Id in (select Account_Id from AccountPhotoModels)
order by Id

open crsr
fetch crsr into @id

While (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin

   exec master.dbo.xp_create_subdir 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\media\images\accounts\' + @id

fetch crsr into @id
end
close crsr
deallocate crsr
```

Does anyone have an idea how to call that system SP within a cursor as I'm trying to do above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assemble the value you want to pass as a separate step:

```
...
declare @path varchar(max)
open crsr
fetch crsr into @id

While (@@fetch_status = 0)
begin
   set @path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\media\images\accounts\' + @id
   exec master.dbo.xp_create_subdir @path

fetch crsr into @id
end
close crsr
deallocate crsr
```

For each parameter, you can pass a *variable* or a *value* - but you can't compute an *expression* to obtain that value.

Comment: OMG! Seriously?!? That simple?? Hilarious, let me give it a try.

Comment: It worked just fine. Thanks. As soon as it will let me, I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `@id` is not `varchar` (but an `int`) you must also do this change:

FROM:

```
set @path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\media\images\accounts\' + @id
```

TO:

```
set @path = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\media\images\accounts\' + Cast(@id as varchar)
```